# T-SQL динамический подзапрос

Tags: sql-server

возникла такая проблема, есть запрос, в котором таблицу нужно постоянно менять, хотелось бы её вынести в переменную, в виде отдельного запроса всё ок, но как это можно впихнуть в другой запрос?  Вот что 'напытался'

```
--ОК РАБОТАЕТ

declare @table_name varchar(20) = 'rfiles_01022020'
declare @sql varchar(max)
select @sql = 'select r.id from rfiles.dbo.' + @table_name + ' as r '
exec(@sql) 


--ЭТО ТО ЧТО НУЖНО БЕЗ ДИНАМИЧЕСКОГО ЗАПРОСА

select * from MO_BUFFER as m
where exists(select r.id from [rfiles].[dbo].[rfiles_01022020] as r )


--ЭТО УЖЕ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ (

declare @table_name varchar(20) = 'rfiles_01022020'
declare @sql varchar(max)
select @sql = 'select r.id from rfiles.dbo.' + @table_name + ' as r '
select * from MO_BUFFER as m
where exists(exec(@sql))
```

PS это для внутренних операций, если вы вдруг хотели мне поведать о опасности SQL инъекций

PPS весь запрос в строку взять не могу, т.к. здесь приведена лишь малая часть его, а так он огромный, с кучей кавычек

```
---НАЧАЛО ЗАПРОСА
update mo_buffer
set 
    RINTECHERR=case when isnull(RINTECHERR,'')='' then 'РК4' else RINTECHERR+',РК4' end,
    [status] = 2
from MO_BUFFER as m
inner join people as p on p.id = m.people
where m.mo_log = @mo_log
and
(case
    when exists (select r.id from [rfiles].[dbo].[rfiles_01022020] as r where r.id = m.people )
        then
```

Comment: Формируй в переменной весь запрос, а не только его часть для WHERE EXISTS.

Comment: @Akina Я в самом низу ведь написал что не вариант...

Comment: Последний запрос, если не считать условия - статический. Значит, в переменную - запихивается. А что кавычек много - так никто не обещал, что будет легко... я уж не говорю о том, что заквотить их в любом редакторе с подсветкой синтаксиса - плёвое дело.

Comment: @Akina  Этот запрос тоже часть другого запроса, это я select для примера написал, а так там case when exists(...) 
Потом, попробовал всё же весь запрос запихать, а там оказались ещё локальные переменные (int и datetime), и если первые конвертировать не проблема, то вторые там используются именно как datetime, нельзя их в строку...

Comment: А выполняемый динамически запрос - такой, как показан, статический и некоррелированный? Если так - может, имеет смысл просто выбирать `COUNT(r.id)`? получить запросом в переменную, и дальше уже эту переменную использовать во втором запросе `WHERE @count > 0` вместо `WHERE EXISTS`? А то если сливать результат EXEC в табличную переменную - то тормоза гарантированы.

Comment: @Akina он не совсем такой, но ваша мысль мне нравится. Я добавил его как он есть, но чёт туплю, если я отдельно допустим так 

`
select top 1 r.id into #t1 from [rfiles].[dbo].[rfiles_01022020]
inner join people as p on p.id = m.people
 where r.id = MO_BUFFER.people
`   его вынесу, то это то-же самое будет условие по сумме?
P.S. Извиняюсь, не умею код в комментарии пихать)

Comment: А какая разница - один или миллион? есть хотя бы один - и ладно... нет - ну и прекрасно...

Answer (score 0):

У вас подзапрос никак не связан с остальной выборкой - выполняйте его отдельно:

```
DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @isExist  bit = 0
    , @TableName    NVARCHAR(500) = N'[rfiles].[dbo].[rfiles_01022020]'

SELECT @SQL = 
    N'IF EXISTS(
        select r.id
        from ' + @TableName + ' as r
    )
        SELECT @isExist = 1;'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@isExist bit OUTPUT', @isExist OUTPUT

select * from MO_BUFFER as m
where @isExist = 1
```

Comment: Вы наверное пока писали ответ, я вопрос дополнил, там чуть посложнее

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать временную таблицу:

```
declare @table_name varchar(20) = 'rfiles_01022020'
declare @sql varchar(max)

if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_table') is not null
    drop table #tmp_table;

create table #tmp_table (id int);

select @sql = 'insert into #tmp_table select r.id from rfiles.dbo.' + @table_name + ' as r '
exec(@sql)

select * from MO_BUFFER as m
where exists(select * from #tmp_table)
```

Comment: да, я так и сделал примерно, только не `select r.id` а `select top 1 r.id`, ибо зачем нам все строки

Answer (score 0):

Создайте синоним

```
Create Synonym rfiles for [rfiles].[dbo].[rfiles_01022020]
```

И используйте его в вашем запросе

```
select * from MO_BUFFER as m
    where exists(select r.id from [rfiles] as r )
```

Понятно, что после выполнения запроса - синонимы нужно удалить.